# Using solutions of 1-D TISE to calculate constants A, B, C

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering

I'm tentatively putting this here as it's a quantum/Schrodinger problem however I'm unable to solve two equations in the way it's done in a text. At the minute I think that I can't do it because I've not understood something so I'm trying the wrong mathematical techniques. Here goes, it's on page 16 of K.S. Krane's Introductory Nuclear Physics...

Given the potential

$$V(x) = 0, x < 0, region 1$$
$$V(x) = V_0, x > 0, region 2$$

For region 1 you get the "typical" result for 1-D time-independent equation
$\psi_1 = Ae^{ik_1x} + Be^{ik_1x}$ and $k_1=\sqrt{(2mE/\hbar^2}$.

And in region 2 the corresponding solutions are $\psi_2 = Ce^{ik_2x} + De^{ik_2x}$
and $k_2=\sqrt{(2m(E-V_0)/\hbar^2}$.

Then at the boundary condition x = 0 gives $A + B = C + D$ and $k_1(A-B) = k_2(C-D)$ from some equations earlier in the book. Obviously at the boundary condition the wave form is required to be continuous for it to be a valid solution. The text goes on to say the D term must equal 0 which therefore, as I understand it, makes the previous two equations now equal $A + B = C$ and $k_1(A - B) = k_2C$.

The next two lines say that when these equations are solved you end up with the following:

$$B = A\frac{1-\frac{k_2}{k_1}}{1+\frac{k_2}{k_1}}$$
and
$$C = A\frac{2}{1+\frac{k_2}{k_1}}$$
Which has me completely lost. I've been unable to algebraically rearrange the equations to reach these solutions, what am I missing? I can only assume that there's a mathematical method that I don't know about (or I can't remember - festive brain fog!) which you can plug these numbers into and the right hand side of the top equation is equal to $C - A$ as $B = C - A$ or that there's a physical reason that I'm missing so I don't understand the concept enough therefore I'm missing an obvious step. The values of A and B are then used to calculate the probability of the wave being reflected at the barrier and A and C used to calculate the probability of transmittance (tunnelling) so I think it best that I understand how to get these results myself.

Any help much appreciated, it's been eluding me since Christmas Eve and I've wasted far too much paper thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your starting equations are:
$$A + B = C\tag{1}$$
$$k_1(A - B) = k_2C\tag{2}$$
Substitute $(1)$ into  $(2)$:
$$k_1(A - B) =k_2(A+B)$$
Multiply out:
$$k_1A-k_1B=k_2A+k_2B$$
Sort the $A$ from the $B$ terms:
$$(k_2+k_1)B=(k_1-k_2)A$$
$$B=A\frac{k_1-k_2}{k_2+k_1}$$
Divide both numerator and denominator by $k_1$:
$$\implies \boxed{B = A\frac{1-\frac{k_2}{k_1}}{1+\frac{k_2}{k_1}}}\tag{3}$$
To get the expression for $C$, add $A$ to $(3)$.